# ssh between two ubuntu machines via WAN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hadoop

We are trying to set-up a two-nodes hadoop clusters on two different machines. 
SSH to localhost without password have been setted up on both machines. And hadoop can run well as single node on each individual machine.

We are at the stage of use ssh to connect to each other's server and trying to copy the pub key to each other's .ssh folder. 
But the problem is  it seems like we cannot even find the server via the ip :

Here is what I get when i am trying to ssh to the other machine:

```
ssh -v jingfang@hadoop-master

OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to hadoop-master [192.168.1.52] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.52 port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
ssh: connect to host hadoop-master port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The other machine get similar response when trying to connect to me. We tried to ssh to other public servers like the server at school, we can log into. 
When using putty, I can connect to my own machine by using the IP address I provided to the other side, but I cannot ssh to the other side. And the other side can putty to its own in the same way but cannt putty to my machine.

We think either b/c the ssh server configuration is not correct or the net configuration is wrong. Here is my ssh_config

```
    # This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
   CheckHostIP yes
   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
   IdentityFile /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_ed25519
   Port 22
   Protocol 2
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

And here is my sshd_config:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Port 22
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin without-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

Please suggest whether we should change any ssh/sshd config or network config. Thank you very much !

Comment: If its over WAN - connecting to a 'local' IP like 192.168.1.52 is unlikely to work. You're likely to need to be at least be able to connect/route to both machines. Using something like a jumphost on the internet that can connect to one machine or a VPN ([Nebula](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/12/how-to-set-up-your-own-nebula-mesh-vpn-step-by-step/) seems designed for this) with one machine somewhere both can connect to would be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the public IP at each location to which you are connected to the internet through, then you need to setup port forwarding on the routers at each location to send that port 22 to the IP of the machine you want at each location. After that is done ssh to the public ip of the other computer, make sure you have password authentication setup on both computers and they each have a generated RSA key. Then you can `ssh-copy-id username@somehost` to copy the key from each machine to the other. After that disable password authentication and enable Public Key Authentication. Then restart ssh. I would consider using a non standard port as well, if you do know that you would need to use that port in the port forwarding instead of 22.

Comment: Thank you Michael! When I am doing port forwarding, should I forward port 22 to my own public IP for the other machines'?

Comment: The port forwarding in the router should point at the IP of the computer connected to that router. This should be done at both locations.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am really new to this. For the public Ip, is it something like this :https://www.showmyipaddress.eu/  ?

Comment: And we are on win10, is this kind of command on cmd would complete the port forwarding ?:                                                                                                    
  netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=2000 connectaddress=69.166.116.110 connectport=80

Comment: The port forwarding is done on the routers web interface not in the computers.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect some understanding of how networking is working (or not) here might be a start.

Essentially - from your description, you have two machines inside a NAT type setup. Now assuming one or more of these are not behind CGN (which rapidly complicates things).

Right now your network looks a little like this

```
                                      School Server
                                          ^
                                          |
                                          |
                                          |
                                          v
                          +-------->   Internet     <----+
                          |                              |
                          |                              |
                          |                              |
                          |                              |
                          v                              v
                      +---+---+                       +--+----<---+
               +----> |Router?|                       |Router?    |
               |      |  NAT A|                       |NAT B |    |
               +      +-------+                       +------+    +
+-------------+                                                    +---------------+
|  Endpoint A |                                                    | Endpoint B    |
|             |                                                    |               |
+-------------+                                                    +---------------+
```

So a few points. Your endpoints, if behind a NAT can start a connection out to a system on the broader internet. However Endpoint B wouldn't know how to route to Endpoint A because they're behind NAT - and connections *out* are masquaraded, and vice versa. They would know however how to route to the school server cause the router at that end would be able to route out to the internet.

This is why endpoint A and B can see the school server (because their traffic can be routed *out*) but they can't see each other (since their IPs are meaningless to each other).

Options would be

1. Port forward at the routers, if possible and set ssh to use those ports if not standard.

This is the *simplest* but assumes the two endpoints are routable, and not behind NAT, or carrier grade NAT and you have the ability to open ports

2. Set up a VPN of some sort. This needs at *least* one system you have some control over and can be reached by both systems. [Nebula](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/12/how-to-set-up-your-own-nebula-mesh-vpn-step-by-step/) is newer but seems a good fit. Then you can treat these systems as if they're on the same lan

Also might want to take a look at [zerotier](https://www.zerotier.com) - same idea, to put the machines involved on the same lan. Its supposed to be simpler, but you're relying on an external service.

3. Setting up IPv6 tunnels would be another option. This is more involved, and needs a reasonable amount of skill *but* once done, would scale pretty well and since you can send traffic over ipv6, you'd be able to simply connect from client to client.

Hurricane electric is the provider of choice, though this is probably the most technically difficult option of the three.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive explanation. One crazy idea is that can we use the school server to finish the task since we can both ssh to it ? For example I install the hadoop under my account and my classmate install hadoop under his account then we ssh bewteen these two accounts?

Comment: There's an ssh jumphost option you want to look up - I suspect you can rather use the school server as a jumphost in either case. Not that familiar with hadoop to know if that'll work. I dabble a lot with home networking so that side, I know a little :D

Comment: Thank you very much !